# How can I set a value for the switch?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this switch for open and close and I'm saving it on firestore. If it's close, then I want the switch to remain 'close'. Like this:

[image]

Currently, what it does is that if I'll go to another page it'll switch back to this, even if the data in the firestore is close:
[image]

These are the codes:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    checkedC: true,
  });

  const handleChange = async (event) => {
    setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
    const value = event.target.checked;
    const status = value.toString();
    let setStatus = "";

    if (status === "true") {
      setStatus = "open";
    } else if (status.toString() === "false") {
      setStatus = "close";
    }

    console.log(setStatus);

    try {
      const res = await firestore
        .collection("status")
        .doc("status1")
        .set({
          status: setStatus,
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log("successfu;ll");
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
          <FormGroup>
            <Typography component="div" variant="h6">
              <Grid component="label" container alignItems="center" spacing={1}>
                <Grid item>Close</Grid>
                <Grid item>
                  <AntSwitch
                    checked={state.checkedC}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    name="checkedC"
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>Open</Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Typography>
          </FormGroup>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

How can I set the switch depending on the status from the firestore? Let's say if it's closed, then the switch will also be closed and does the same too for open.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the initialState of your checked based on the value from the fireStore.

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState(() => //Read the value from the fireStore);
```

[Lazy Initialization](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/use-state-lazy-initialization-and-function-updates)